# How to fetch Bearer Token from an external Rest API in SpringBoot and then use it for other endpoints for authorization?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, servlets, jwt

I have been trying to fetch a Bearer token from this external Rest API using springBoot and I cannot understand much. I have used Spring Security with my own Rest APIs but I am having a problem with this. I am given below the details of the API I am using as well as headers and parameters needed.

**Authentication**

```
Path: https://qa2.sunbasedata.com/sunbase/portal/api/assignment_auth.jsp
Method: POST
Body:
{
"login_id" : "test@sunbasedata.com",
"password" :"Test@123"
}
```

For example If I want to use the token generated when using the above credentials for this endpoint where I can create a new customer by passing the necessary body, headers and params.

**Create new Customer**

```
Path: https://qa2.sunbasedata.com/sunbase/portal/api/assignment.jsp
Method: POST
Parameters:
cmd : create
Header:
Authorization: Bearer token_recieved_in_authentication_API_call
Body:
 {
"first_name": "Jane",
"last_name": "Doe",
"street": "Elvnu Street",
"address": "H no 2 ",
"city": "Delhi",
"state": "Delhi",
"email": "sam@gmail.com",
"phone": "12345678"
}
first_name and last_name are mandatory parameters.
Response:
Success: 201, Successfully Created
```

I tried fetching the token but there was error that the Get Method was not accepted:

> Resolved
> [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' is not supported].